# Magento - How to get attribute position

Tags: magento

How do I get position for an attribute? I want to maintain the order of attribute list in the state.phtml, so need retrieve the position set in the backend for each attribute.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get with below code

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load( $code, 'your_attribute_code');
$option_col = Mage::getResourceModel( 'eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
 ->setAttributeFilter( $attribute->getId() )
 ->setStoreFilter()
 ->setPositionOrder( 'ASC' );
$option_col->getSelect()->order('main_table.sort_order '.$orderby);
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Hi, I found position is stored in catalog_eav_attribute, how can I query that?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out! I should use getResourceModel instead of getModel for eav tables.